# Cargar y filtrar una tabla en html, MVC, ASP aplicando linq recursivo?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp

Estoy realizando un tabla usando HTML en ASP.NET MVC.
Estoy cargando en ella la información del Estado de resultados de la empresa, y son bastantes registros, y al momento de cargar la tabla se tarda bastante tiempo, al igual que al querer filtrar información, ya que vuelve a cargar los datos (los filtros son por fechas).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede observar la tabla es tipo árbol, ya que las cuentas están relacionadas entre ellas, una cuenta puede tener muchas cuentas hijas y las hijas pueden tener hijas, y así hasta `N` veces. 
La cuenta padre lleva la suma de sus hijas y así hasta llegar al ultimo padre

Para llenar la tabla uso una vista recursiva, a continuación muestro el código para llenar y crear dicha tabla.

```
@helper GetHtml (List<SUI.Web.Common.Entidades.Dashboard.BG> Modelo, String Padre_ID, int con)

{
    <table align="center" border="1"class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-hover" id="tab1">

        @{
            string currentID = "";
            int rowIndex = 0;
            var lis = (Modelo.Where(a => a.CuentaPTPadre == Padre_ID)).ToList();

            foreach (var i in Modelo.Where(a => a.CuentaPTPadre == Padre_ID))
            {
                if (i.CuentaPT == currentID)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (con == 0) { 
                    con = 1;
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Nombre</th>
                                <th>Cuenta</th>
                                <th>Importe</th>
                                <th>Importe 2</th>


                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                    }
                rowIndex++;
                currentID = i.CuentaPT;
                var Sub = Modelo.Where(a => a.CuentaPTPadre.Equals(i.CuentaPT)).ToList();
                var NuevoModelo = Modelo.Where(a => !a.CuentaPT.Equals(i.CuentaPT)).ToList();
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @if (Sub.Count > 0)
                                {
                                    <span class="icon icon-e" style="float:left; cursor:pointer;" id="iconv" onclick="b()"></span>
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <span style="display:inline-block;width:14px">&nbsp;</span>
                                }
                                @i.Nombre
                            </td>
                            <td>@i.CuentaPT</td>
                            <td>@i.Importe </td>
                            <td>@i.importe2</td>

                        </tr>
                        <tr style="display:none;">
                            @if (Sub.Count > 0)
                            {
                                <td colspan="4" class="innerTable">
                                    @NestedData.GetHtml(NuevoModelo, i.CuentaPT,1)
                                </td>
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <td colspan="4" ></td>
                            }
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>

                }
            }
        }

    </table>
}
```

El modelo lo lleno desde el controlador, para llenar el modelo hago un `foreach` que separe las cuentas y después relacione dichas cuentas (padres e hijas) pero esto es algo lento, lo intente usando linq, pero solo lo logre hasta 2 niveles, ¿habría una forma de hacerlo usando solo linq de modo recursivo hasta `N` niveles?

en resumen, mi pregunta es, ¿existe una manera más facil de relacionar las cuentas hijas con sus padres?

¿es mejor obtener la suma de las cuentas hijas desde la consulta o sumar directamente en el llenado de la tabla?

¿Podrían ayudarme a realizar una tabla que cargué más rápido, y que al momento de filtrar no tenga que volver a cargar el modelo y llenar la tabla?, o si alguien tiene otra solución se lo agradecería bastante.

Comment: Se me ocurre que utilices recursividad, al menos así lo hago en f#.

Comment: También pensaba usar recursividad, pero no he encontrado la manera de hacer recursividad con linq, ¿tendrás algún ejemplo?

Comment: En realidad no me refería a usar recursividad con linq sino al algoritmo de carga de tus datos. ¿cómo es la estructura de tu tabla? si dices que tienes que cargar dos veces tus datos igual y se puede mejorar la estructura. También prueba a usar una estructura de árbol en tu modelo, y así te evitas el tener que usar linq para sacar los hijos